# React JS : Migrate from server rendering to pure client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp, serverside-javascript

I have react project which was previously setup using node js server, and which utilises both client side and server side rendering and routing. I need to move it so that it uses pure client side rendering/routing. How do I go about doing that?

The server.js file looks like this:

```
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var routes = require('./public/js/' + defaultAppName + '/' + defaultAppName + '.node.js');

app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {

  var location = new Location(req.path, req.query);

  try {
    Router.run(routes(), location, function (e, i, t) {
      var str = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        React.createElement(Router, i));
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return next();
  }
});
```

The directory structure looks like-

```
|- server.js
|- gulpfile.js
|- public
  |- js
    |- app.node.js
|- src
  |-jsx
    |  |-app
    |  |  |-actions
    |  |  |-components
    |  |  |-reducers
    |  |  |-routes
    |  |  |-index.html
  |-sass
    |  |-app
    |  |  |-main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove routes from server side code and Serve index.html of your app for any url and let routing to handled by your application entry point. e.g

```
var static_path   = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
app.use(express.static(static_path));

     app.get('/', function (req, res) {
         res.sendFile('index.html', {
             root: static_path
         });
     });
```

Inside entry point of app e.g app.jsx

```
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var Routes = require('/path/to/routes');

ReactDom.render(Routes, document.querySelector('.any-place-on-dom'));
```